# How to create entries w/ relationships through Models

Tags: relationships, ee5

I am having trouble saving a ChannelEntry with a relationship to another ChannelEntry using the Models Service.

The following produces no errors, but a row in exp_relationships with no field_id

```
$entry = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry')
  ->with('Children', 'Channel')
  ->filter('entry_id', 330)->first();

$child = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry')->filter('channel_id', 7)->filter('title', 'My title')->first();

$entry->Children[] = $child;
$entry->save();
```

In the Control Panel, this shows no relationships have been set. I can manually add the field_id to the DB, and *poof* the relationship is created.

So how do I create the relationship with the field_id column populated?

Also, I noticed it also creates a row in the exp_channel_data_field_23 (the id of my relationship field) with a NULL value in the field_id_23 column. Adding a relationship through the Control Panel does not produce a row in this table at all, however...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to set an array with a 'data' property to the field. So from my example:

```
$entry->field_id_23 = ['data' => [$child->entry_id]];
$entry->save();
```